# Module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'colors'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I am running an Anaconda installation of Python3 64bit on Windows. I have no idea how to put those words in a proper sentence, but I hope it gives enough information. I am taking an Udacity course which wants me to run `%matplotlib inline`. This gives the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'colors'

I get the same error when I run `from matplotlib import pylab`, but i get no error from `import matplotlib`.

I installed matplotlib as follows: `conda install -n tensorflow -c conda-forge matplotlib`.

How do I solve this error?

Kind regards

**Per request:**
`conda list` gives

> matplotlib                2.1.0                    py36_1    conda-forge

and a list of other modules.

Comment: Although I don't think this is the cause of the problem, you're missing the `-c` before `conda-forge`. Is that a typo? Can you show the output of `conda list`?

Comment: Thanks. The ``-c`` was a typo.  I assumed you only wanted the matplotlib part of ``conda list``. Let me know if you want to see more.

Comment: Are you running the magic command (`%matplotlib inline`) in a Notebook, or IPython? In either case, did you install the relevant package to the `tensorflow` environment and activate the environment before running the commands?

Comment: I am running the magic command from a jupyter notebook which I started by ``activate tensorflow`` and then ``jupyter-notebook``. The matplotlib package is installed to the ``tensorflow`` environment (see the ``-n`` flag in the ``conda install`` command).

Comment: Did you install the Jupyter Notebook to the `tensorflow` environment? Also, the command to start the notebook is `jupyter notebook` not `jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: I installed the Jupyter Notebook to the tensorflow environment. If not wouldn't I see different errors than a matplotlib import error? Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The issue was that I needed to restart the notebook in order for the installations to take effect. Why can't my successes be as glorious as my failures?

Answer (score 5):

The notebook needs to be restarted for the new installations to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to upgrade matplotlib.

> pip3 install -U matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured out your why you are getting that error, `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'colors'`

In your code are you calling: `plt.colors` ?? If so, try `plt.plot` instead.

That fixed my issue with:
https://github.com/alberduris/ML0120EN/blob/master/Module%201%20-%20Introduction%20to%20TensorFlow/1.3ML0120-LinearRegression.ipynb

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
converter = plt.plot
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that (1) the question you have answered is from over 6 years ago and (2) the question was already answered in the comments and in another answer.